# Color Ramp Particle System Not Working With Age

Tags: particles, color

I am new to blenders particle system and I am pretty bad at texturing, but I decided to do a particle system anyway. I trying to get the color to change over time but every solution I find does not help. Am I doing something wrong?!?! I have tried the image below, adding another divide and changing view port shade mode but nothing is helping! [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Nice, I was kind of looking for a result that sort of slowly transitions the color from one to another as its ages off.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uClc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uClc.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be in both CYCLES rendering engine and in RENDERED preview. I can't tell from your picture, but the material must be on the object being used as the particle instance. I made a test file and I'll post it here. I can confirm this is working 100% on my machine.

[image: PARTICLES]

File is here -- [image]

Comment: FYI - Lifetime and End values both are set to 200.